# Displaying closest div based on different factors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have different file inputs I want displayed once the previous one has been selected.  At the moment I have

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group inputMargBtm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileOneContainer" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileOne" name="fileOne" class="fileGroup" accept=".jpeg,.jpg">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="filePadd">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div id="hideDivTwo" class="hiddenDiv">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileTwoContainer" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileTwo" name="fileTwo" class="fileGroup" accept=".jpeg,.jpg" disabled="true">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I also have a lot more hidden rows for up to 10 inputs.  So I dont need to create new code for each input within my Javascript, I am trying to display things dynamically.  Essentially, if I select a file, it should display the next file input.

At the moment I have this

```
$(".fileGroup").on('change',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id.length) {
        $(this).parents('.row').nextSibling('.row').child('.hiddenDiv').css("display", "table-footer-group");
    }
});
```

So I get the id of the changed fileGroup.  I then attempt to get its parents row, then get the next row, and display its hidden div.  At the moment this does not seem to work.  What would be the best way to display the next input block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```js
$(".fileGroup").on('change',function(){
var $next_element = $(this).parents('.row').next('.row').find('input[type="file"]');
if ($next_element.length) {
  $next_element.prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group inputMargBtm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileOneContainer" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileOne" name="fileOne" class="fileGroup" accept=".jpeg,.jpg">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="filePadd">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div id="hideDivTwo" class="hiddenDiv">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fileTwoContainer" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                            Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="fileTwo" name="fileTwo" class="fileGroup" accept=".jpeg,.jpg" disabled="true">
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is rather simple:
1. grab `.row` parent
2. look for the next element with `.row` class
3. find an file input in the next `.row` element
4. if the input exists, set its disabled attribute to 
 `false`